# R friendly greek characters

Tags: r, character-encoding

I noticed that I can use some Greek letters as names while others will be either illegal or just aliases to letters from the latin alphabet.

Basically I can use `β` or `µ` (though `β` is changed to `ß` when printing and `ß` and `β` act as alliases)

```
list(β = 1)
# $ß
# [1] 1
list(μ = 1)
# $µ
# [1] 1
```

α, Γ, δ, ε, Θ, π, Σ, σ, τ, Φ, φ and Ω are allowed but act as alliases to latin letters.

```
list(α = 1)
# $a
# [1] 1

αa <- 42
aa
# [1] 42

GG <- 33
ΓΓ 
# [1] 33
```

Other letters I've tested just don't "work":

```
ι <- 1
# Error: unexpected input in "\"
Λ <- 1
# Error: unexpected input in "\"
λ <- 1
#Error: unexpected input in "\"
```

I was surprised about `λ` as it's defined by the package `wrapr`'s `define_lambda`, so I assume this depends on the system.

I know similar or identical looking characters can have different encodings, and some of them don't go well with copy/paste between apps, the code of this question returns the described output when pasted back to RStudio.

[`?make.names`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html) says :

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number

So part of the question is : what's a letter ? and what's going on here ?

More specifically:

- Are there greek characters that will safely work on all R installations, in particular, are `µ` and `β` (or `ß`) safe to use in a package.
- why isn't `λ` ( `intToUtf8(955)` ) usable on my system while it seems to be commonly use by `wrapr`'s users.
- Are there other non latin letters, greek or not, that I could safely use in my code ? (for instance Norwegian `ø` looks cool and seems to work on my system)

This all was prompted by the fact I'm looking for a one (or 2) character function name that wouldn't conflict with an existing or commonly used name, and would look a bit funky. `.` is already used a lot and I use [`..`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotdot/index.html) already as well.

from `sessionInfo()` :

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252
```

Comment: Encoding hell. `assign("λ", 1); 
assign("α", 1); 
ls(); 
enc2native("λ"); 
enc2native("α"); enc2native("Γ")`

Comment: This works apparently: `assign("λ", 5); get("<U+03BB>")`, but not `assign("λ", 5); print(λ)`. Interesting find this question. Also this: ``assign("λ", 5); `<U+03BB>` `` works.

Comment: I suppose `assign("λ", 5); print(λ)` works when your native encoding is *utf-8* : `enc2utf8("λ")`

Comment: ü, ä, ö, ß work well on my system but that might be locale dependent. Even a German wouldn't naturally use `ß` as a variable name, so that might work well.

Comment: FWIW, I'm on Ubuntu and I don't receive any error/alias whatsoever and can't reproduce anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not an expert by any means but let's try to analyze the problem. In the end, your R-code needs to be understood by the compiler therefore the source-code of make.names() may be helpful:

```
names <- as.character(names)
names2 <- .Internal(make.names(names, allow_))
if (unique) {
  o <- order(names != names2)
  names2[o] <- make.unique(names2[o])
}
names2
```

Now, .Internal() calls the R-interpreter (written in C) so we need to go a little deeper. The C-code responsible for handling the make.names() request can be found here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/0dccb93e114b00b2fcbe75e8721f11a8f2ffdff4/src/main/character.c

A short snipped:

```
SEXP attribute_hidden do_makenames(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
{
    SEXP arg, ans;
    R_xlen_t i, n;
    int l, allow_;
    char *p, *tmp = NULL, *cbuf;
    const char *This;
    Rboolean need_prefix;
    const void *vmax;

    checkArity(op ,args);
    arg = CAR(args);
    if (!isString(arg))
    error(_("non-character names"));
    n = XLENGTH(arg);
    allow_ = asLogical(CADR(args));
    if (allow_ == NA_LOGICAL)
    error(_("invalid '%s' value"), "allow_");
    PROTECT(ans = allocVector(STRSXP, n));
    vmax = vmaxget();
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    This = translateChar(STRING_ELT(arg, i));
    l = (int) strlen(This);
    /* need to prefix names not beginning with alpha or ., as
       well as . followed by a number */
    need_prefix = FALSE;
    if (mbcslocale && This[0]) {
        int nc = l, used;
        wchar_t wc;
        mbstate_t mb_st;
        const char *pp = This;
        mbs_init(&mb_st);
        used = (int) Mbrtowc(&wc, pp, MB_CUR_MAX, &mb_st);
        pp += used; nc -= used;
        if (wc == L'.') {
        if (nc > 0) {
            Mbrtowc(&wc, pp, MB_CUR_MAX, &mb_st);
            if (iswdigit(wc))  need_prefix = TRUE;
        }
        } else if (!iswalpha(wc)) need_prefix = TRUE;
    } else {
        if (This[0] == '.') {
        if (l >= 1 && isdigit(0xff & (int) This[1])) need_prefix = TRUE;
        } else if (!isalpha(0xff & (int) This[0])) need_prefix = TRUE;
    }
    if (need_prefix) {
        tmp = Calloc(l+2, char);
        strcpy(tmp, "X");
        strcat(tmp, translateChar(STRING_ELT(arg, i)));
    } else {
        tmp = Calloc(l+1, char);
        strcpy(tmp, translateChar(STRING_ELT(arg, i)));
    }
    if (mbcslocale) {
        /* This cannot lengthen the string, so safe to overwrite it. */
        int nc = (int) mbstowcs(NULL, tmp, 0);
        if (nc >= 0) {
        wchar_t *wstr = Calloc(nc+1, wchar_t);
        mbstowcs(wstr, tmp, nc+1);
        for (wchar_t * wc = wstr; *wc; wc++) {
            if (*wc == L'.' || (allow_ && *wc == L'_'))
            /* leave alone */;
            else if (!iswalnum((int)*wc)) *wc = L'.';
        }
        wcstombs(tmp, wstr, strlen(tmp)+1);
        Free(wstr);
        } else error(_("invalid multibyte string %d"), i+1);
    } else {
        for (p = tmp; *p; p++) {
        if (*p == '.' || (allow_ && *p == '_')) /* leave alone */;
        else if (!isalnum(0xff & (int)*p)) *p = '.';
        /* else leave alone */
        }
    }
//  l = (int) strlen(tmp);        /* needed? */
    SET_STRING_ELT(ans, i, mkChar(tmp));
    /* do we have a reserved word?  If so the name is invalid */
    if (!isValidName(tmp)) {
        /* FIXME: could use R_Realloc instead */
        cbuf = CallocCharBuf(strlen(tmp) + 1);
        strcpy(cbuf, tmp);
        strcat(cbuf, ".");
        SET_STRING_ELT(ans, i, mkChar(cbuf));
        Free(cbuf);
    }
    Free(tmp);
    vmaxset(vmax);
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return ans;
}
```

As we can see, compiler-dependent datatypes such as wchar_t (http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/unicode_wchar_t.html) are used. This means that the behavior of make.names() depends on the C-compiler used to compile the R-interpreter itself. The problem is that C-compilers aren't very standardized therefore no assumption about the behavior of characters can be made. Everything including operating system, hardware, locale etc. can change this behavior.

In conclusion, I would stick to ASCII characters if you want to be save, especially when sharing your code between different operating systems.