# Calling data frames with their greek equivalent names

Tags: r, character-encoding

I accidently run into this today where I noticed that while I saved a data frame as `df`, I could call it with the equivalent greek letters. (I forgot I set my keyboard to Greek).

[image]

After investigating a bit, I couldn't see why this works. At first I thought that it worked say for greek equivalent of english. Like `b & β` or `a & α` or `d & δ` but not for letters with no greek equivalent like `j`. However this happened,

[image]

Any idea what is happening here?

My session info:

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] data.table_1.14.2 forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.8       purrr_0.3.4       readr_2.1.2       tidyr_1.2.0       tibble_3.1.6      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.1.3   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.1.3      jsonlite_1.8.0   lubridate_1.8.0  lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
[12] rlang_1.0.2      reprex_2.0.1     rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.2        cli_3.2.0        haven_2.4.3      xml2_1.3.3       withr_2.5.0      httr_1.4.2       fs_1.5.2         generics_0.1.2  
[23] vctrs_0.3.8      hms_1.1.1        grid_4.1.3       tidyselect_1.1.2 glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.2      readxl_1.3.1     tzdb_0.2.0       modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.2  
[34] backports_1.4.1  scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-3 utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.6    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.12     crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce: `d <- head(iris) ; δ` gives `Error: object 'δ' not found` (R 4.2.0 on Windows 10)

Comment: Weirdly, it looks like it's translating  β to ß ...?

Comment: @Aurèle I added my session info

Comment: @BenBolker I also tried it with `v` which translates to 'vita' in greek but same result

Comment: You might look into updating to R-4.2, where UTF-8 support is vastly improved.

Comment: @r2evans but is this the case? Maybe something with the IDE? In any case, it doesn't affect me. I don't use greek letters

Comment: And I can reproduce with R 4.1.0. So upgrading to R 4.2.0 should solve it.

Comment: @Aurèle But is it a bug? Or extra functionality? :P

Comment: I'm at two disadvantages here: I don't use UTF-8 often (all of my clients use English, me too) and I am holding off on upgrading to R-4.2 until more of my tools are more thoroughly tested against its list of breaking changes. Sorry, it was a thought, I don't know that it solves anything.

Comment: There is a similar question with a fairly good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55531887/r-friendly-greek-characters)